# Dynamically create adaptive cards with different content using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: javascript, botframework

I'm trying to create an adaptative cards carousel to my Azure chatbot.

I have a list of objects and for each item of this list, I want to create a new adaptative card.

Here is where I'm sending the cards carousel:

```
await step.context.sendActivity({
            text: "I've found the following job positions:",
            attachments: this.createCards(positions),
            attachmentLayout: AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel
        });
```

And here is the `createCards`:

```
const JobCard = require('../../resources/jobCard.json');
createCards(positions) {
    let cards = [];         
    positions.forEach(function(position) {
        let cardJson = JobCard;
        cardJson.body[0].columns[0].items[0].text = position.name;
        cardJson.body[0].columns[0].items[1].text = position.activities;  
        let adaptativeCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(cardJson);
        cards.push(adaptativeCard)
    })
    return cards;}
```

The issue is: all the cards are displaying the same content. The number of cards being displayed is accordingly with the number of `positions`, but all the cards are displaying the `position.name` and `position.activities` of the first `position` of `positions`.

The question: What's is wrong with the way I'm trying to dynamically create the cards? How can I successfully accomplish this?

It feels like I'm missing something really simple here, but I couldn't find what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your cards references are pointing to the same object, so when you modify one of them, you end up changing all of them. To prevent this behavior, create a copy of the card each time you make a new one. You can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JobCard))` to create a deep copy of a JSON Object. Here is how your code should look.

```
createCards(positions) {
    let cards = [];         
    positions.forEach(function(position) {
        let cardJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JobCard));
        cardJson.body[0].columns[0].items[0].text = position.name;
        cardJson.body[0].columns[0].items[1].text = position.activities;  
        let adaptativeCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(cardJson);
        cards.push(adaptativeCard)
    })
    return cards;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the JobCard in a JSON file, you could also specify it in a JavaScript file and export a function that takes a position as an argument and returns a JobCard. Here is an example:

```
// JobCard.js
function JobCard(position) {
  return {
    $schema: 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
    type: 'AdaptiveCard',
    version: '1.0',
    body: [
      {
        type: 'Container',
        items: [
          {
            type: 'TextBlock',
            text: 'Your Job',
            weight: 'bolder',
            size: 'medium',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'Container',
        items: [
          {
            type: 'FactSet',
            facts: [
              {
                title: 'Activity:',
                value: position.activity,
              },
              {
                title: 'Name:',
                value: position.name,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
}

module.exports = JobCard
```

```
// createCards.js
const { CardFactory } = require('botbuilder')
const JobCard = require('./JobCard')

function createCards(positions) {
  return positions.map(position => CardFactory.adaptiveCard(JobCard(position)))
}

module.exports = createCards
```